# Jetpack Compose - Column - Gravity center

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I'm creating a layout with Jetpack Compose and there is a column. I would like center items inside this column:

```
 Column(modifier = ExpandedWidth) {
        Text(text = item.title)
        Text(text = item.description)
 }
```

Answer (score 307, accepted):

You can use [these parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#column):

- [**`horizontalAlignment`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Alignment.Horizontal.html) = the horizontal gravity of the layout's children.
- [**`verticalArrangement`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement.Vertical)= the vertical arrangement of the layout's children

Something like:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
        Text(
                text = "First item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
                text = "Second item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
                text = "Third item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
}
```

[image]

If you want only to center horizontally just use:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Column (  ) { ... }
```

[image]

Comment: if you are using a Row, any idea align them so one composable function is at the start and another at the center? something like spaceEvenly in flexbox in css or like in `Row` widget in flutter https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html you can use mainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly

Comment: @PeterHaddad https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#align and check this post: https://joebirch.co/android/exploring-jetpack-compose-column

Comment: I was getting error on `align`, but I update the jetpack compose dependency to `1.0.0-alpha03` and it worked. Previously it was `1.0.0-alpha02` thank you!

Comment: You can simply use `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` instead of `Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight()`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Maybe off topic, but how would you center the text "TopAppBar" in your image? That's actually why I am here :)

Comment: @Rafael Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67497414/how-to-align-title-at-layout-center-in-topappbar/67499847#67499847

Answer (score 89):

You can use

```kotlin
Text(
  text = item.title,
  textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
  modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
)
```

- textAlign is for aligning text inside the box.
- Modifier.align() is    for aligning text box inside column

Comment: `Modifier.align` is only for `BoxScope`

Comment: textAlign is the correct answer

Comment: `textAlign = TextAlign.Center` is correct. Note that it doesn't belong to `modifier`.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Column view's alignings]

You can find details in attachment by looking figures of all possibilities of aligning view inside column.
Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
   Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    )
```

Comment: This one is definitely the one to use, Last version of Composable 1.0.0 and more

Answer (score 10):

```
Text(
 "Hello World", 
 textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
 modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp)
)
```

You can use `TextAlign` attribute to center the texts.

Reference - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66391295/2227743

Comment: to test set `heightIn(min = 40.dp)` and see that it is just centred horizontally

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively you can create your own composable and use it everywhere:

```
@Composable
fun Center( modifier: Modifier = Modifier, content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        content = content
    )
}
```

And you use like this:

```
Center {
    Text(text = "Text 1")
    Text(text = "Text 2")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't like it too much, but this is what it worked to me:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
                //Your composable elements
            }
```

Compose 1.0.0-beta07

Comment: `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` instead of `Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight()`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `textAlign` property of `Text` composable

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    text = item.title,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
)
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    text = item.description,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **`Arrangement.Center`**

- Place child components as close to the center of the main axis

SAMPLE CODE

```
@Composable
fun Column(

    arrangement: Arrangement = Arrangement.Center,

)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the option to apply gravity on the individual items as follows then it will center the items.

```
Column(modifier = ExpandedWidth) {
       Text(modifier = Gravity.Center, text = item.title)
       Text(modifier = Gravity.Center, text = item.description)
}
```

Comment: This answer is deprecated, as `Text` doesn't allow `Gravity` now

Comment: `Text(text = item.title, modifier = Modifier.gravity(Alignment.CenterHorizontally))`

Comment: With `alpha07`, use `Text(text = item.title, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment. CenterHorizontally))`

Comment: Modifier ```align``` for ```Text``` doesn't exists for ```1.0.0-beta09```version of Compose.

Comment: The suggestions above don't work (at least with Compose 1.0.0) but this does:
`style = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)`

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `0.1.0-dev09` you can modify the gravity or arrangement attributes by using the parameters `horizontalAlignment` and `verticalArrangement`

```
@Composable
fun centeredColumn() {
    return Column (
        modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp), 
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, 
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
            Image(asset = imageResource(id = R.drawable.ic_emojo_logo_white))
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.login_subtitle))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you are using lazyColumn to load list and want make whole item center
you can use this

```
LazyColumn( horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```kotlin
modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
```

Comment: Works great with buttons!

Answer (score 2):

```
 Column(
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
     horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
     ){
       // Child Composable Here Like Text, Row, Box, Image ... more 
     }
```

`verticalArrangement` -> Make all Child Composable Center Vertically to Column(Parent)

`horizontalAlignment` -> Make all Child Composable Center Horizontally to Column(Parent)

Answer (score 1):

**Update: This answer is outdated.**

You can use `Column(crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center)` . It works like gravity.

Comment: unfortunately it's not available in dev-03

Comment: Related to Flutter not JetpackCompose

Answer (score 1):

You could use FlexColumn to bring content in the center as it supports CrossAxisAlignment.

```
FlexColumn(crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center) {
    inflexible {
        Text(text = item.title)
        Text(text = item.description)
    }
}
```

Warp it inside inflexible so that widgets will not occupy the full screen.

In the same way if you want to bring views to the center of the screen with FlexColumn than use mainAxisAlignment along with crossAxisAlignment

```
FlexColumn(mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.Center,
        crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.Center) {
    inflexible {
        Text(text = item.title)
        Text(text = item.description)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it as of the latest version of compose(0.1.0-dev05)

For you to center the text inside this container, you need to use the `LayoutAlign` modifier.

```
Column(modifier = LayoutWidth.Fill + LayoutAlign.Center) {
    Text(text = item.title)
    Text(text = item.description)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To center horizontally

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Text(text = item.title)
        Text(text = item.description)
 }
```

To center both horizontally and vertically in the parent surface

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().fillMaxHeight(), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Text(text = item.title)
        Text(text = item.description)
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Text(
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    text = "We are making some improvements. Please, try again later."
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?