# How do layouts work in Jetpack Compose and how do they relate to XML?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have some text.
I want to centre it on the screen.
I am using Jetpack Compose.
How do I do this?
I know that there are three types of layouts in Jetpack Compose.

- Box
- Column
- Horizontal

Which one should I use?
I don't know how layouts work.
Are they full screen by default like in XML?
If so, how do I position elements like ConstraintLayout?
How do I set padding and margin from only one side and how do I link elements?

Comment: There seem to be to many question at once. Did you check out the [Jetpack compose pathway](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose)? It should answer some of the questions already.

Comment: I was doing it, but I got confused.

Comment: They were only giving it for specific use cases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713224/jetpack-compose-column-gravity-center/62152703#62152703

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess all your questions can be clarified if you follow the [Compose Pathway](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose). But I'll try to summarize for you...

You can organize your components using one of the following "layout managers" (which in Compose are just called layouts):

- `Column` (similar to `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation)
- `Row` (similar to `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation)
- `Box` (similar to `FrameLayout`)
- and `ConstraintLayout`.
  If you need something different of these, you can create a custom layout using the `Layout` composable.

*"Which one should I use?"*
You can use any of these, depending of the case... To simply display a text in the center of the screen, you can achieve with all of them.

Using `Column`:

```
Column(
    Modifier.fillMaxSize(), // to fill the whole screen
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Text(text = "Hello")
}
```

Using `Box`

```
Box(
    Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Text(text = "Hello",
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
}
```

*"Are they full screen by default like in XML?"*
No, they are "wrap_content" by default.

*"how do I position elements like ConstraintLayout? How do I set padding and margin from only one side and how do I link elements?"*
You need to declare the references to the components and then positioning them accordingly.

Here is a simple example...

```
ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)) {
    // Creating refs...
    val (text1Ref, edit1Ref, btn1Ref, btn2Ref) = createRefs()
    Text("Name", 
        // Linking the reference to this component
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(text1Ref) {
        // linking the top of this component to the parent top
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
    })
    TextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {},
        label = { Text("Name") },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)
            .constrainAs(edit1Ref) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                // linking this component with the previous component
                top.linkTo(text1Ref.bottom)
            })
    Button(onClick = {},
        content = { Text("OK") },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp).constrainAs(btn1Ref) {
            end.linkTo(edit1Ref.end)
            top.linkTo(edit1Ref.bottom)
        }
    )
    TextButton(onClick = {},
        content = { Text("Cancel") },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)
            .constrainAs(btn2Ref) {
                end.linkTo(btn1Ref.start)
                baseline.linkTo(btn1Ref.baseline)
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: How do I add a background to the constraint layout?

Comment: `ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Red) {...}`
You can use a custom color by doing `Color(0xff0000)` or using a resource `colorResource(R.color.purple_200)`

Comment: But if I want to use an image?

Comment: Well... my guess would be add `Image` as the first child..


```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.recife),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```