# How to align title at layout center in TopAppBar?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-appbar

```
TopAppBar(
       backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
       elevation = 0.dp,
       modifier= Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
       navigationIcon = {
               IconButton(
                   onClick = { TODO },
                   enabled = true,
               ) {
                   Icon(
                       painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.icon_back_arrow),
                       contentDescription = "Back",
                   )
               }
           }
       },
       title = {
           Text(
               modifier = if (action == null) Modifier.fillMaxWidth() else Modifier,
               textAlign = if (action == null) TextAlign.Center else TextAlign.Start,
               maxLines = 1,
               text = "Hello"
           )
       },
       actions = {
           action?.run {
               Text(
                   modifier = Modifier
                       .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                       .clickable(onClick = TODO),
                   color = Color.Green,
                   text ="Cancel",
               )
           }
       }
```

I'm new in jetpack and want to align title of TopAppBar at center if action is null. Title is not align center of layout. when there is no navigationIcon it work but adding navigationIcon it show slightly right. How can I do it to make title text at center of layout.

Comment: Keep `Text` as wrap Content and Set its gravity to center relative to parent .

Answer (score 52, accepted):

With **Material3** you can simply use the [**`CenterAlignedTopAppBar`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#CenterAlignedTopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarColors,androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarScrollBehavior)):

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title = { Text("Centered TopAppBar") },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                contentDescription = "Localized description"
            )
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

---

With **Material2** you have to use the other constructor of [`TopAppBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TopAppBar(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) that has no pre-defined slots for content, allowing you to customize the layout of content inside.

You can do something like:

```
val appBarHorizontalPadding = 4.dp
val titleIconModifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
    .width(72.dp - appBarHorizontalPadding)

TopAppBar(
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    elevation = 0.dp,
    modifier= Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

    //TopAppBar Content
    Box(Modifier.height(32.dp)) {

        //Navigation Icon 
        Row(titleIconModifier, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {                
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high,
            ) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = { },
                    enabled = true,
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_add_24px),
                        contentDescription = "Back",
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        //Title
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

            ProvideTextStyle(value = MaterialTheme.typography.h6) {
                CompositionLocalProvider(
                    LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.high,
                ){
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        text = "Hello"
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        //actions
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Row(
                Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                content = actions
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the CompositionLocalProvider do in this case, and why is it mandatory?

Comment: @Gabriele can you please describe what's the purpose of CompositionLocalProvider here?

Comment: @DarshAnsari Take the compose theme codelab for this, or refer to the docs. It is just to override the default values taken up  Row inside. By default, some Composable get their values by internal composition providers. This behaviour can be overridden, or customised, by using CompositionLocalProvider to "provide" a custom value, i.e., the alpha, in this case.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Your code does not seem to work properly : the action block is placed under the navigation icon instead of the end of the toolbar (using your Material 2 answer).

Comment: What is "actions" here

//actions
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Row(
                Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                content = actions
            )
        }

Comment: Here is the answer I was looking for "CenterAlignedTopAppBar". Thanks

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Material3, you can use the `CenterAlignedTopAppBar` as well.

```
fun CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    colors: TopAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(),
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null
) {
    SingleRowTopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = title,
        titleTextStyle =
        MaterialTheme.typography.fromToken(TopAppBarSmallTokens.HeadlineFont),
        centeredTitle = true,
        navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
        actions = actions,
        colors = colors,
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
}
```

[image: Center-aligned top app bar image]

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** the old answer is out of date, please use **CenterAlignedTopAppBar**

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = titleRes)) },
    actions = {
        IconButton(onClick = onActionClick) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = actionIcon,
                contentDescription = actionIconContentDescription,
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
            )
        }
    },
    colors = colors,
    modifier = modifier,
)
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

I redid the native implementation a bit.

Need to do just two things:

1.Add this file to your project. This is a slightly modified implementation of the `TopAppBar` class.
https://gist.github.com/evansgelist/aadcd633e9b160f9f634c16e99ffe163

2.Replace in your code **TopAppBar** to **CenterTopAppBar**. And it's all!

```
  Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            CenterTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        text = text,
                    )
                },
```

**EDIT**
extension's code

```
val Number.toPx
    get() = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        this.toFloat(),
        Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    )
```

Result
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: unable to import ```import com.klikatech.rollo.ui.extensions.common.toPx```

Comment: added this code to my main answer

Comment: CenterAlignedTopAppBar is not handling the long title. The title text overlaps with the right/action icons.

Answer (score 4):

The core of the title centering is that the space of the left and right occupying slots is the same. You only need to adjust the default size of the slots. We give the left and right slots the default space occupying slots, which can solve this problem well, and the code is simple.

```
@Composable
fun TopBar(title: Int, actions: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null, popOnClick: () -> Unit) {

    val modifier = Modifier.size(width = 70.dp, height = 50.dp).background(Color.Red)

    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = title), fontSize = 16.sp,
             textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) },
        navigationIcon = {
            Box(modifier = modifier, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                IconButton(onClick = { popOnClick() }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "", tint = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                }
            }
        },
        actions = {
            Box(modifier = modifier, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                if (actions != null) {
                    actions()
                }
            }
        },
        backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
        elevation = 1.dp
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It depends what's in the appbar.

If you only have the title, then you could do the following:

```
topBar = {
        TopAppBar(content = {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                text = "Title Text",
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
            )
        })
    },
```

If you have an icon either side you should be able to do the same, may have to adjust things if have two icons one side and one the other, then may want to use add a same sized icon to even things out and put enabled to false to it's not clickable and color to transparent so it's not seen, otherwise you could try and figure out the size and add padding end to the text, it seems you also need to add 16.dp padding to the transparent icon, as the navigation icon is given extra padding before the title but not between title and actions

Here's what I did for the arrowIcon and title

```
 topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            navigationIcon = {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "back arrow icon"
                    )
                }
            },
            title = {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Basic Navigation",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                )
            },
            actions = {
                IconButton(
                     modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 16.dp),
                    enabled = false,
                    onClick = {}
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                        contentDescription = "back arrow icon",
                        tint = Color.Transparent
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a begginer with Jetpack Compose and before I searched for a solution of that problem I tried to figure my own, maybe it will be enough for someone. I needed centered title for TopAppBar with navigation icon on the left side only or with two icons on the left and right side, this solution was OK for me. Later I configurated that for including passed icon on the right side or no.

```
        TopAppBar(
            backgroundColor = Color.Green,
            elevation = 5.dp,
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                // size of an icon and placeholder box on the right side
                val iconSize = 32.dp

                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = "Arrow Back",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            navController.popBackStack()
                        }
                        .size(iconSize)
                )
                Text(text = "Centered Title", fontSize = 32.sp)
                // placeholder on the right side in order to have centered title - might be replaced with icon
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(iconSize)
                ) { }
            }
```

I can't attach screenshot, preview is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNQTF.png

Answer (score 0):

I found a good workaround if you're using Material 2.
Create a Row, that contains:

- Column with **weight 1**, containing an Icon
- Column with **weight 1**, containing Header
- Spacer with **weight 1**

The device's screen will automatically divide into 3 equal sections.
Here is a code sample:

```kotlin
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                backgroundColor = Transparent,
                elevation = 0.dp,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                /** TopAppBar Content */
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(51.dp).fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    /** Icon*/
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f).padding(start = 9.dp)) {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(22.dp)
                                .height(22.dp),
                            enabled = true,
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back),
                                contentDescription = "Back",
                                tint = ThemeBlue
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    /** Header */
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            maxLines = 1,
                            text = "Header",
                        )
                    }
                    /*TODO
                     * When the stable version of Material 3 comes out
                     * we should replace the whole TopAppBar with CenterAlignedTopAppBar.
                     * For now, this Spacer keeps the Header component in the center of the topBar
                     */
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                }

            }
        },
        content = {
            Divider(color = ThemeBlue, thickness = 0.5.dp)
        }
    )
```

Here is a screenshot of the result this code produces:

[image: TopBar]

Answer (score 0):

Use fillMaxWidth() to let the Text View occupy AppBar width
Use wrapContentWidth(align = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) to align the Text Title.

```
TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Text(
                text = screenname,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentWidth(align= Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
        },
        modifier = modifier
    )
```

Comment: You're missing some code in `modifier = modifier`: the `modifier` variable is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
title = {
        Row(
            modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                stringResource(R.string.app_title).uppercase(),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
            )
            Spacer(modifier.width(1.dp))
        }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Composable
fun TopAppBarCompose(){

    TopAppBar(
        title = {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(
                    text = "Hello",
                    fontSize = 30.sp,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        },
    )
}
```

Comment: Does not really work well once you add a navigation icon, then it will be centered between the icon and the end of the component

Answer (score -3):

The previous solutions are too complex. It is actually quite simple:

```
title = {
    Text(
        text = "title",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

Comment: it will leave some space in the start

Comment: Exactly what I found: a space in the start of the text

Comment: Add an end padding in the modifier of 16 dp then the text component will have a horizontal spacing of 16 dp and a perfectly centred aligned title.