# Jetpack Compose align Text content to center of the Scaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

**My Problem:**

I want to place my Text() content to center of the page in Scaffold.

I tried "textAlign = TextAlign.Center" - It align the text in horizontal area alone. Not align the text in vertical area.

**My code:**

```
@Composable
fun ScaffoldWithTopBar() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Top App Bar")
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {}) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, "backIcon")
                    }
                },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                contentColor = Color.White,
                elevation = 10.dp
            )
        }, content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color(0xff8d6e63)),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {

            }
            Text(
                text = "Content of the page",
                fontSize = 30.sp,
                color = Color.White
            )
        })
}
```

Note: I haven't place this text into Column. I used directly.

**My output:**

[image]

**Question:**
How to place the text into the center of the parent?

Comment: Check also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713224/jetpack-compose-column-gravity-center/62152703#62152703

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign the `fillMaxSize()` to the parent container, not to the `Text`:

```
   Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
       contentAlignment = Center
   ) {
       Text(
           text = "Content of the page",
           fontSize = 30.sp,
           modifier = Modifier
               .background(Color(0xffb3e5fc)),
       )
   }
```

or:

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Text(
        text = "Content of the page",
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffb3e5fc)),
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You are helping our community. My doubt - without container (Column) it will not work?

Comment: @RanjithKumar No

Comment: I updated code in my question. If possible can you check my code?

Comment: @RanjithKumar in the new code, you are using the Text outside the Column

Answer (score 1):

You need to place it inside a `Box`, and specify `contentAlignment`

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    Text(
        text = "Content of the page",
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffb3e5fc)),
    )
}
```

If you wanna align different `Box` children differently, you can use `.align` modifier for each item. Note that it's only available inside `BoxScope`, also there's same modifier for `Column` and `Row`.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    Text(
        text = "Content of the page", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffb3e5fc))
            .align(Alignment.Center)
    )
}
```

Comment: align modifier not available in compose version 1.0.1. 
Without any container it will not work ?

Comment: @RanjithKumar yes, it's `BoxScope` modifier, you still need to place your item inside a `Box`

Answer (score 1):

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.social_list_empty),
            style = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
```

[image]

Reference : For more sample codes of Jetpack Compose, check [this](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2021/08/03/jetpack-compose-1-0-0-sample-codes/)

Answer (score 0):

The content in Scaffold is a Composable function in which there is no position info for items by default. In your case, the default position of Text is the top left of its parent view. The solutions putting the Text inside the Box/Colum works, as now Text is put in the center of the Box or Colum, which takes the whole screen. We see Text is in the center of the screen, while the truth is Text is in the center of Box or Colum.