# Is there something like TextView’s center_vertical in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I’d like to find some properties like `android:gravity=“center_vertical”` in Jetpack Compose without using Column, any ideas?

Comment: is this an answer for you ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713224/jetpack-compose-column-gravity-center

Comment: Where is the problem to use a `Box` or a `Column` as container?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti no problems actually, I just wanna to find out whether a container is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place a text vertically center without using a container. But you can change the alignment of `Text` without using a container.

```
Text(textAlign: TextAlign.Center)
```

In case of height with `wrapContent` this will automatically place the text vertically centered.

Other values of TextAlign are `Left`, `Right`, `Justify`, `Start` and `End`

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way is to use a container. And that is exactly how it should be used in Compose: the container does not add any problems, unnecessary load, etc. No reason why you should avoid them.

To me, using `Column` is not the most logical solution, because it is designed to vertically arrange several elements.

For a single item, `Box` is more clear to me:

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Text("Hello")
}
```